# How can I look up words with digammas?

Tags: greek, resource-request, dictionary, aeolic

*(Digammas? Digammai? Digammata?)*

[This question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7268/406) revolved around a dialectal form that I'd never seen before. Normally when encountering a new Greek word, Attic or otherwise, my first instinct is to look it up in [Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph).

However, the input guide on Perseus doesn't list digamma. Is there a better way to look up a word like Aeolic *ϝε*? (I'm not even sure if LSJ include forms like that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can enter searches in Beta code (which is what LSJ is underlyingly in), the Beta code for digamma is V.

If I enter "ve" in the link you gave, Perseus understands it well enough, but says it has no matches: "Sorry, no information was found for ϝε."

Having extensively customised the LSJ and Morpheus for the TLG, I have to say, I'm not that surprised. The TLG (for which I no longer work) certainly will recognise it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for. However, searching for `ve` in the TLG's LSJ gives only one hit, *Ϝέλχανος*. How would I search in order to find the actual word *ϝε*?

Comment: @Draconis Has ϝε ever been attested epigraphically?

Comment: @AlexB. I have no idea tbh; I never saw it before that question.

Comment: @Draconis That's the problem. As far as I can see (partly based on Blümel 1982), we can find ϝε only in Balbilla 28 (line 12), on (the left leg of?) the Memnon colossus in Egypt. But this is not "real" Lesbian/Aeolic.

Comment: @Draconis In section 20.8. **Digamma and hiatus**, Gary Miller (Miller 2014) talks of "the tradition that profers ϝ- in reflexive (and, with little exception, only these) forms, as noted by Lobel (1925: §4) and many scholars since then (cf. HGD ii. 92f." (p. 249).

Comment: A search on the TLG LSJ will likely only match headwords. But if VE is in the corpus, eg in Balbilla, and you click it, it should point to its morphological analysis and matching headwords.

Comment: Like I tried to say earlier, and I would like to reiterate it, digamma never occurs in Lesbian ins­criptions. This is a well-known fact.

Answer (score 5):

Believe it or not, it is actually in L&S, here:

http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.53:9:95.LSJ

In the alphabet waw comes after epsilon. But L&S ignore it for the purposes of lemmatisation.

Comment: Oh, nice! That answers the specific question I had. For the general case, are you saying I should search without the digamma, then look for it in the specific entry?

Comment: I think so.....

Answer (score 4):

In [the Brill Dictionary of Ancient Greek](http://dictionaries.brillonline.com/montanari) (ed. by F. Montanari, **behind a paywall**/subscription only), you can directly type/choose ϝ into the search field:

[image]

There's also a very handy iOS app of the above-mentioned dictionary (in Italian only though) https://www.loescher.it/gi#4 - I use it quite a lot.